# Connection between selenium and browser is getting disconnected getting Below Error

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

When only browser is launching and not performing any actions and quiting the browser then getting below Error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 105; received: 0
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:180) ~[httpcore-4.4.3.jar:4.4.3]
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

When browser is launching and performing 1 or 2 actions and quiting the browser.
PFB for error trace.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 123
        at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Base64Encoder.mapCharToInt(Base64Encoder.java:89)
        at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Base64Encoder.decode(Base64Encoder.java:76)
        at org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$2.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:57)
        at org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$2.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:55)
        at org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$3.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:75)
        at org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$3.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:73)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.getScreenshotAs(FirefoxDriver.java:343)
    10:59:31.659 [Firefox] ERROR c.c.zucchini.AbstractZucchiniTest - ERROR running test:
    cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 123
        at com.comcast.zucchini.TestNGZucchiniRunner.runCukes(TestNGZucchiniRunner.java:80) ~[zucchini-2.2.9.jar:2.2.9]
        at com.comcast.zucchini.AbstractZucchiniTest.runWith(AbstractZucchiniTest.java:255) ~[zucchini-2.2.9.jar:2.2.9]
        at com.comcast.zucchini.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:51) [zucchini-2.2.9.jar:2.2.9]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 123
        at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Base64Encoder.mapCharToInt(Base64Encoder.java:89) ~[selenium-api-2.49.1.jar:na]
        at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Base64Encoder.decode(Base64Encoder.java:76) ~[selenium-api-2.49.1.jar:na]
        at org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$2.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:57) ~[selenium-api-2.49.1.jar:na]
        at org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$2.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:55) ~[selenium-api-2.49.1.jar:na]
        at org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$3.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:75) ~[selenium-api-2.49.1.jar:na]
        at org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$3.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:73) ~[selenium-api-2.49.1.jar:na]
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.getScreenshotAs(FirefoxDriver.java:343) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-2.49.1.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code to TestNGZucchiniRunner? It looks like it's having an issue with an array.

Comment: I have not added any array code in ZucchiniRunner File. Moreover, I have just extends AbstractZucchiniTest class in my RunnerFile.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @KyleFairns I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I have mention in answer.

Comment: KyleFairns @helgi, I guess, there is already an issue in selenium.
I have refer this, but there is no solution given in this ticket. could you please let me know how to resolve this issue?
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5014